# how can we find n sqrt(m) and check whether the answer is an integer in c++

Tags: c++, c++14

this is the method i have tried so please help if you have any suggestions.can using templates solve this problem

```
#include <iostream>
`#include<math.h> 
 using namespace std;

int main()
{
 long double m=0;
long double n=0,ans=0;//is this wrong
 int t;
cin>>t;
for(int i=0;i<t;i++)//here t is testcases
{
   cin>>n>>m;
   ans=pow(m,1.0/n);
   if(floor(ans)==ans)//this is to check if ans is int
   cout<<ans<<"\n";
   else 
   cout<<"-1"<<"\n";
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: just check whether `floor` or `ceil` of number is equal to itself.

Comment: Sufficiently large numbers in floating-point arithmetic are always rounded to integers, so checking whether `sqrt` returns no fractional part is insufficient. But we need examples of your input numbers and what "various" methods you've tried.

Comment: If you provide more details, that would be helpful. For example, what is the min and max (aka the range) or `m` here? What are your test cases? Please elaborate.

Comment: constraints 1<t<10^5,1<n<30,1<=m<=10^9

Comment: i have mentioned the constraints and problem but the code is incorrect in some test cases

Comment: @akhiltata m ≤ 10^9 eliminates the rounding concern, but imprecision in `pow` can still throw it off. Providing *one* input which fails is more useful to us than "try 10^5 inputs."

Comment: You need to round to the nearest integer, then check r (rounded value) is a root by testing r*r*r ... n times == i;

Answer (score -1):

```
long double m;

long double value = sqrt(m);

if(floor(value) == (value)) {
    cout << "Sqrt of given number is integer \n";
}
```

One more small suggestion. In you program at line number 14 `ans=pow(m,1.0/n);`. Use `powl()` instead of `pow` because you variable of type `long double`

**Edit :** As suggested by Potatoswatter in comment section of this answer, `C++` overloads `pow()` so there's no need to spell out `powl()`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath> 
using namespace std;

int main() {
    long double m; // No need to assign zero
    long double n,ans; // No need to assign zero
    int t;
    cin >> t;

    for(int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        cin >> n >> m;
        ans = powl(m,(1.0/n));
        if(floor(ans) == ans)//this is to check if ans is int
            cout << ans <<"\n";
        else 
            cout << "-1" << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Doing `ceil` as well as `floor` won't change the equality test. C++ overloads `pow` so there's no need to spell out `powl`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter : ceil and floor of an integer will remain the same. Where as for real number other than integer, It will have different number.

Comment: True, but the code in the question already got that right. This is only making it needlessly more complicated.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Yes, I totally agree with you. I have also edited my answer.

Comment: @potataoswatter can you put the code i have to change guys

Comment: @akhiltata : I have edited my answer and it will work for you. AFAIK you can to check whether `m^(1/n)` is an integer number of not.